# How to combine two lines that share the same keyword?

Tags: bash, scripting

lets say I have a file looking somewhat like this:

```
X NeedThis1 KEYWORD
.
.
NeedThis2 X KEYWORD
```

And I need to combine the two lines into one like this:

```
NeedThis2 NeedThis1 KEYWORD
```

It needs to be done for every line in that file that contains the same KEYWORD but it can't combine two lines that look like this (two X's at the first|second position)

```
X NeedThis1 KEYWORD
X NeedThis2 KEYWORD
```

I am considering myself bash-noob so any advice if it can be done with something like awk or sed would be appreciated.

Comment: It can be done with `awk` and `sed` but you need to post some relevant data to attract good solutions. For eg. Is that `X` really stated as `X` in your file? What's the format of `NeedThis1`? etc

Comment: yes the X is really X in my file and NeedThis is some name of file like print.o. Basically the two NeedThis are both files where one is caller of the other one via the KEYWORD.

Comment: And the KEYWORD is a function from the first file that calls the second file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
awk '
    {if ($1 == "X") end[$3] = $2; else start[$3] = $1} 
    END {for (kw in start) if (kw in end) print start[kw], end[kw], kw}
' file
```

Answer (score 1):

**Try this:**

```
awk '
$1=="X" {key = $NF; value = $2; next}
$2=="X" && $NF==key {print value, $1, key}' file
```

**Explanation:**

- When a line where first field is X, store the last field as key and second field as value.
- Look for the next line where second field is X and last field matches the key stored from pervious action.
- When found, print the value of last matched line along with first field of the current line and the key.
- This will most definitely break if your data does not match the sample you have shown (if it has more spaces or fields in between), so feel free to adjust as per your needs.

Comment: Thank you too, I appreciate your effort and would vote both answers correct if it was possible.

Answer (score 0):

I won't give you the full answer, but if you have some way to identify "KEYWORD" (not in your problem statement), then use a BASH associative array:

```
declare -A keys
while IFS= read -u3 -r line
do
  set -- $line
  eval keyword=\$$#
  keys[$keyword]+=${line%$keyword}
done
```

you'll certainly have to do some more fiddling, but your problem statement is incomplete and some of the work needs to be an exercise for the reader.

Comment: Thanks, but I dont know the keywords... I just want to look into the file and when I see two same keywords then combine the lines into one.

Comment: Well, that scriptlett will combine the text of all lines that have the same final token.  If "final token" means "keyword", then you just dump out all the found keywords and the associated text. -- well, first associated text *then* the keyword, to get the result you ask for.

Comment: Per your updated problem comment, you populate keys with: keys[$keyword]=valid and select text where you have ${keys[$keyword]} is "valid" and the line starts with or has a keyword preceded by an "X".  Short of actually doing the problem for you, I think that should get you going.